# Como puedo acceder a una lista generica desde otra clase en c#

Tags: c#, poo, lista, clase

Hola como podria acceder a los valores de la lista desde otra clase en c#?
tengo el siguiente codigo

```
        class CLASE1
        {
        
            private string nombre;
            private string correo;
        
        
            List<string> lista=new list<string>();
        
            public void setNombre(string prmNombre)
                   {nombre = prmNombre;}
        
                   public string getNombre()
                   {return nombre;}
        
        
                   public void setCorreo(string prmCorreo)
                   {correo = prmCorreo;}
        
                  public string getCorreo()
                  {return correo;}
         
         public void agregar datos()
         {
           Console.ReadLine();
           lista.Add(getNombre());
           Console.ReadLine();
           lista.Add(getCorreo());
         }
        
        
     }
```

y tengo este codigo en la clase 2 a la que quiero acceder a los datos de la lista

```
class CLASE2 
  {
     CLASE1 obj =new CLASE1();
     

 }
```

No se como podria acceder a los datos de mi lista, he intentado con el objeto que cree en la clase 2, pero me devuelve la lista sin valores adentro. gracias espero puedan ayudarme

Comment: Lo que hiciste es instanciar la clase1 que no es un objeto, crea una clase aparte de estas dos que incluya solo las propiedades string nombre {get; set;} y usa esta misma como objeto.

Comment: en c# existe la maravilla del `{get;set;}` lo que significa que si nesesitas datos de otra clase, tienes q llamar a la funcion para retirar los datos ej.`n_clase copia = objeto_creado.get();`

Answer (score 2):

Agrego código comentado en los lugares que considero son más relevantes, adaptado a C#:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Clase1 clase = new Clase1();
        clase.AgregarDatos();

        foreach(var s in clase.Lista){
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        
    }
}


class Clase1{

    /* 
    En C# el código:

    private string nombre;

    public void setNombre(string nombre){
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public string getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }

    puede reemplazarse por:

    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    */
    public string Nombre {get;set;}
    public string Correo {get;set;}
    
    // lista de tipo tupla (string,string) para guardar nombre y correo, 
    // al no colocarle public por defecto era privada y por ese motivo 
    // no lo veias al instanciar la clase1 desde la clase2.
    public List<(string,string)> Lista {get;set;}

    public Clase1(){
        Lista = new List<(string,string)>();
    }

    public void AgregarDatos(){
        // ReadLine devuelve la línea leída

        // leer nombre
        string nombre = Console.ReadLine();

        // leer correo
        string correo = Console.ReadLine();
   
        // agregar a la lista la tupla (nombre,correo);
        Lista.Add((nombre,correo));
    }

}
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda :D pero una pregunta: lo del constructor era necesario?? porque no le pasaré variables por parametro a la lista a la hora de crear el objeto en el Main

Comment: Es un constructor por defecto, no recibe ningún parámetro, la función que hace solamente es inicializar la lista cuando se crea un nuevo objeto. Si deseas puedes quitarlo e inicializar la lista al declararla `public List<(string,string)> Lista {get;set;} = new List<(string,string)>();`